# error al instalar composer con xampp

Tags: php, xampp, composer

El instalador me arroja el siguiente error:

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

A setting in your registry could be causing the problem. Check this value and remove it if necessary:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun = @mode 20,5 & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq SoundMixer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "SoundMixer.exe">NUL && exit & if exist "C:\Users\dimmu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe" ( start /MIN "" "C:\Users\dimmu\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SoundMixer\SoundMixer.exe" & tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit ) else ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "explorer.exe">NUL && exit & explorer.exe & exit )
```

Comment: sería ideal si agregas a tu pregunta el procedimiento de manera clara que sigues para instalarlo para complementar junto con el mensaje de error

Comment: Usando el instalador del composer(siguiente, siguiente)